# Overlapping start/end date range aggregation by day in R

Tags: r, aggregation, date-range

I've searched many questions to see if I could find an answer, but nothing quite fits what I am trying to do. So I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  Area  Start       End
1   9     2016-06-30  2016-07-07
2   9     2016-07-01  2016-07-04
3   8     2016-06-21  2016-06-28
4   8     2016-06-23  2016-06-25
5   8     2016-06-25  2016-06-30
```

What I have done is created a data frame that has the entire date range for each area with a blank column for the aggregate number of days. Maybe there is an easier way to do this, or a package that can handle this scenario, but I am hoping to come up with something that looks like this:

```
Area  Date        Count
...               0
9     2016-06-30  1
9     2016-07-01  2
9     2016-07-02  2
9     2016-07-03  2
9     2016-07-04  2
9     2016-07-05  1
9     2016-07-06  1
9     2016-07-07  1  
9     2016-07-08  0
...               0
8     2016-06-21  1
8     2016-06-22  1
8     2016-06-23  2
8     2016-06-24  2
8     2016-06-25  3
8     2016-06-26  2
8     2016-06-27  2
8     2016-06-28  2
8     2016-06-29  1
8     2016-06-30  1
...               0
```

Seems like there should be an easy way to handle an array like this in R, but I haven't found it yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(your_df) # or setDT to convert in-place

# convert dates to Dates (assuming they aren't)
dt[, Start := as.Date(Start, '%Y-%m-%d')]
dt[, End := as.Date(End, '%Y-%m-%d')]

# expand the dates, then aggregate
dt[, .(Date = seq(Start, End, by = 1), Area), by = ID][, .N, by = .(Date, Area)]
#         Date Area N
#1: 2016-06-30    9 1
#2: 2016-07-01    9 2
#3: 2016-07-02    9 2
#4: 2016-07-03    9 2
#...
```

Comment: Just missing the counts of 0 where there is no event. But this answer solves the gist of the question.